# Displaying more radio buttons based on radio selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I honestly have no clue on where to begin with this. I know how to do it with basic html but I have to pull the questions from the database but I feel like this way is much more complicated.

What makes it confusing is that I need to use a for loop to display all the top level questions. Then when they select Yes to the top level question it then displays a lower level question. Right now I only have the top level questions displaying because I have no idea how to get it unlock the lower level questions.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery(function($){

    // Prevents errors in old IE.
    if(!window.console || !window.console.log) window.console = {log: function(){}};

    // Enable debugging for complex logic.
    var debug = true;

    function checkConditions(inputs, views){
      views.each(function(){
        var view = $(this);
        var conditions = view.attr('data-view-conditions').split(',');
        var display = true;

        // Loop over all required conditions to be met.
        for(var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++){
          var name = conditions[i].split(':')[0];
          var value = conditions[i].split(':')[1];
          var input = inputs.filter('[name="' + name + '"]:checked');

          if(debug) console.log('\nRecalculating view conditions.');

          if(!input.length){
            display = false;
            if(debug) console.log('View not show as no :checked input with the name "' + name + '" was found.');
          }else{
            if(value != undefined && input.val() != value){
              display = false;
              if(debug) console.log('View not show as no :checked input with the name "' + name + '" has the value of "' + input.val() + '". Value needed was: "' + value + '".');
            }
          }
        }

        if(display){
          view.css({display: 'block'});
        }else{
          view.css({display: 'none'});
        }

      });
    }

    $('form').each(function(){
      var form = $(this);
      var inputs = form.find('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
      var views = form.find('[data-view-conditions]');

      // Recalculate which views to be shown each time the inputs change.
      inputs.on('change', function(e){
        checkConditions(inputs, views);
      });

      // Check conditions to set up required view state on page load.
      checkConditions(inputs, views);
    });

  });
  </script>

   <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->



<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Submit a Ticket</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.4.2/forms-min.css">
<style>
.myForm {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 768px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form name="ticket1" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked myForm" action="flashpoint_processing.php" method="post">

<h2>Submit A Ticket</h2>


<legend> Your Details </legend>
<label> 
<span>First Name: </span>
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
</label>
<label>
<label> 
<span>Last Name: </span>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
</label>
<label>  
<span> Business Name </span>
    <input id="Busname" name="Busname" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
 </label>

<label>Phone</label>
    <input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
<label>Extension</label>

    <input id="Ext" name="Ext" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-small">
<label> E-mail</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>

<label>Preferred Method of Contact</label>
      <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact-0" value="Phone" checked="checked">
      Phone
      <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact-1" value="Email">
      Email


<label>
<legend>Issue</legend>  
<?
$topq = array();
$topid = array();
$results = mysql_query("select questions, ID from tbl_questions where top=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $topq[] = $row['questions'];
    $topid[] = $row['ID'];
};

for($i=0;$i<count($topq);$i++){
    echo "<label>";
    echo $topq[$i];
    echo "</label>";
    echo " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"question+$i\" id=\"$i\" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\">No
      <input type=\"radio\" name=\"question+$i\" id=\"$i+1\" value=\"2\">Yes";
    echo $topid[$i];
    echo "<br>";
};
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="ticket" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.
http://jcsites.juniata.edu/students/bookhjr10/flashpoint/test6.html

If we could just hard code the questions in I could do it easily but they want to pull it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery will change your life. You can set an event listener for each radio button, and then in the change event, do an ajax call to load the new items into an array from the server, then simply iterate through that array and generate html. Then you can use the .html() method to inject the generated html into the selected div :)